# Creating Dataset from spreadsheetML

Tags: c#, dataset, spreadsheetml

Is there any way to create a dataset from a spreadsheetML using C# without using Interop.Excel?

Answer (score 0):

The following link shows how you can use openXML's spreadsheetml to create a dataset without Interop.Excel:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd920313.aspx

You can also use this method: http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/dennis/archive/2008/02/29/getting-data-from-excel-the-fast-way-using-linq.aspx